# javascript toggle function causes page to scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small problem with a webpage returning back to the top of the page after a javascript function is executed.

Basically, I have a small javascript function that toggles the visibility of a div by changing it's display style. the code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

I then call this with a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('001');" class="expand">[+/-] Hide/Show Info</a>
```

and the div looks something like this:

```
<div id="001" style="display:none;">
hello world
</div>
```

This works just fine. But when I click on my "expand/hide" link to toggle the visibility of the div, the page always returns to the top, so I have to scroll back down to the bottom every time.

I have tried adding the the following changes at the end of my javascript function, but neither of them works:

```
window.location = 'test.php#' + id; //where test.php is my current page
```

and

```
window.location.hash=id;
```

Any help would be appreciated in fixing this issue
Thanks.

Comment: The use of `<!-- -->`within the script tag is deprecated.

Comment: @reporter thanks, I'll remove it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is recommended to not overload a link, but use a span instead:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/65dxok10/)

```
<style>
.expand { cursor:pointer; }
</style>

<span data-div="x001" 
 class="expand">[+/-] Hide/Show Info</a>
```

Also I strongly recommend to

- not use numerical IDs
- not use inline event handlers

So

```
window.onload=function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll(".expand");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].onclick=function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  
      var ele = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-div"));
      if (ele) ele.style.display = ele.style.display == "block"?"none":"block";
    }
  }
}
```

using

```
<div id="x001">...</div>
```

---

With a link, you can use a page as href to tell the user to enable JS or suffer the consequences :)

```
<a href="pleaseenablejs.html" data-div="x001" 
 class="expand">[+/-] Hide/Show Info</a>
```

---

To fix **your** code you need to return false. In newer browsers, use event.preventDefault

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var elm = document.getElementById(id);
   elm.style.display = elm.style.display == "block"?"none":"block";
   return false;
}
```

using

```
<a href="#" onclick="return toggle_visibility('001');" 
 class="expand">[+/-] Hide/Show Info</a>
```

Comment: c) not use `href="#"`

Comment: `javascript:void(null);` works perfectly fine when JS is disabled: it does nothing. Whereas, `href="#"` still kicks you to the top of the page if JS is disabled.

Comment: -goes to try it- Hmm, nope, not giving me a 404!

Comment: Hmm, it used to. Never mind. It is ugly and breaks right-click, open in new tab and if you do not like # use a span

Comment: I tried the above and return false just makes the link stop working. Also, numerical IDs are only used as example, they have nice descriptive names normally. I'll change my links to spans though as everyone seems to thinks this is a better idea. Thanks for the help

Comment: Return false on its own will stop the link - you still need to toggle the div. Also if you chose to change to a span, please accept my answer since I suggested it

Answer (score 3):

after the click event your link redirects the url to "#" as you are not stopping event propagation.

you can achieve that by changing your href `javascript:void(0)`.

If you ask why [here your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0).

Comment: @mplungjan I will change the link to a span though, for the reasons you mentionned. Thanks for the help :) Please don't sigh because of me :)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('001');" class="expand">[+/-] Hide/Show Info</a>
```

Comment: that also means onclick is not going to work which also means nothing is working. also there is no no-js fallback.

Comment: I tried this and it gives me an "access forbidden 403 error"